# Unexpected key 'PrincipalTags' found: getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

we are using custom federation broker and calling getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity to get token and exchange that with assumeRoleWithWebIdentity.

Code executes perfect on local system but when I upload it to lambda functions then it gives error:

```
2021-02-10T05:41:46.387Z 5623ada0-fca9-4918-aab6-e3878ac2d621 ERROR exception occurred during sign in 

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'PrincipalTags' found in params
at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9
at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9 {
code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
time: 2021-02-10T05:41:46.386Z
} UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'PrincipalTags' found in params
at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9
at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9
```

Can anyone please suggest what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. The version of the AWS SDK that ships with Lamdba isn't up to date.

I ran `npm install aws-sdk` to override the included version. Once I did this I was able to send PrincipalTags.

See also: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-aws-sdk-latest-version/